# graphql server email verify example

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-server

I'm starting to work on an express API using graphql with `apollo-server-express` and `graphql-tools`. My register user process steps are:

1. User submit user name, email and password.
2. Server send an email to user by Mailgun with unique link generated by `uuid`.
3. User follow the link to verify the registration.

But I'm in struggle at how to bind the mutation in the resolver. See snippets:

**server.js**

```
  const buildOptions = async (req, res, done) => {
    const user = await authenticate(req, mongo.Users)
    return {
      schema,
      context: {
        dataloaders: buildDataloaders(mongo),
        mongo,
        user
      },
    }
    done()
  }
  // JWT setting
  app.use('/graphAPI',
    jwt({
      secret: JWT_SECRET,
      credentialsRequired: false,
    }),
    graphqlExpress(buildOptions),
    res => data => res.send(JSON.stringify(data))
  )
```

**Mutation on resolver**

```
 signupUser: async (root, data, {mongo: { Users }}) => {
      // Check existed accounts,
      // if account is not exist, assign new account
      const existed = await Users.findOne({email: data.email})
      if (!existed) {
        // create a token for sending email
        const registrationToken = {
          token: uuid.v4(),
          created_at: new Date(),
          expireAfterSeconds: 3600000 * 6 // half day
        }
        const newUser = {
          name: data.name,
          email: data.email,
          password: await bcrypt.hash(data.password, 10),
          created_at: new Date(),
          verification_token: registrationToken,
          is_verified: false,
        }
        const response = await Users.insert(newUser)
        // send and email to user
        await verifyEmail(newUser)
        return Object.assign({id: response.insertedIds[0]}, newUser)
      }
      // Throw error when account existed
      const error = new Error('Email existed')
      error.status = 409
      throw error
    },

    // VERIFY USER
    // Set verify to true (after user click on the link)
    // Add user to mailist
    verifiedUser: async (root, data, {mongo: { Users }}) => {
      await Users.updateOne(
        { email: data.email },
        {
          set: {is_verified: true},
          unset: {verification_token: {token: ''}}
        }
      )
    },
```

**route config**

```
routes.get('/verify?:token', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('verified', {title: 'Success'})
})
```

the route config is where I stuck, because the object is passed to all resolvers via the context inside `graphqlExpress`

Any one help me out or suggest for me any articles related. Thanks so much.

Comment: check [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45294962/how-to-email-authentication-api-with-graphql-and-passport#comment77564484_45294962) and the links I gave there

Comment: yes, it was a long road to read those stuffs and I've learn a lot from those,  the problem I'm stuck here is how to mutate resolver to set `is_verified` field to `true` when server send a link `mydomain.com/verify?:token` to user and user click on that link to confirm account.

Answer (score 2):

You will need 3 graphql endpoints and 1 apollo http endpoint for proper workflow.

Optionally you can combine 3 graphql endpoints in one, but then it will be a one big function with a lot of different responsibilities.

1# graphql endpoint: changepass-request

- expects email param

1. check if user with such email found in db:
2. generate code
3. save it in the local account node
4. send code to the user email with http link to confirm code:
   http://yoursite.com/auth/verify?code=1234
5. return redirect_uri: http://yoursite.com/auth/confirm-code
   for UI page with prompt for confirmation code

2# graphql endpoint: changepass-confirm

- expects code param:
- if user with such code found in db, return redirect_uri to UI page with prompt for new pass with confirmation code in params: http://yoursite.com/auth/change-pass?code=1234

3# graphql endpoint: changepass-complete

- expects code and new pass:

1. hash new password
2. search in db for local account with such code
   3a. if not found:
   return error with redirect_uri to login page:
   [http://yoursite.com/auth?success=false&message="Confirmation](http://yoursite.com/auth?success=false&message=%22Confirmation) code is not correct, try again."
   3b. if found:
   change password for new, return success status with redirect_uri to login page:
   [http://yoursite.com/auth?success=true&message="ok"](http://yoursite.com/auth?success=true&message=%22ok%22)

4# apollo HTTP endpoint: http://yoursite.com/auth/verify?code=1234

- if no code provided:
  redirect to UI registration page with error message in params:
  [http://yoursite.com/auth?success=false&message="Confirmation](http://yoursite.com/auth?success=false&message=%22Confirmation) code is not correct, try again."
- if code provided: search in db for local account with such code
  1a. if user not found:
  redirect to reg ui with err mess in params:
  [http://yoursite.com/auth?success=false&message="Confirmation](http://yoursite.com/auth?success=false&message=%22Confirmation) code is not correct, try again."
  1.b if user found:
  redirect to ui page with new password prompt and attach new code to params

I didn't put any code above, so you can use this workflow in other auth scenarios.

Comment: I was just running into the same problem with GraphQL and found this solution. Thanks a lot!!

I guess GraphQL doesn't allow for a more elegant solution. Adding endpoints for each purpose just feels a little clumsy. That's not a criticism targeted at your elaborate solution but rather a sigh!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like rather than utilizing the `verifiedUser` endpoint, it would be simpler to just keep that logic inside the controller for the `/verify` route. Something like:

```
routes.get('/verify?:token', (req, res) => {
  Users.updateOne(
    { verification_token: { token } },
    {
      $set: {is_verified: true},
      $unset: {verification_token: {token: ''}}
    },
    (err, data) => {
      const status = err ? 'Failure' : 'Success'
      res.render('verified', {title: status})
    }    
  )
})
```

Comment: yes, thanks for help @Daniel, I refined as my case a bit  by change the <query> to `{verification_token: { token: req.params.token } }` 
the url on the email is cool now, but my db (mongodb) wasn't updated, (I changed `set` and `unset` to `$set` and `$unset` as mongodb documents)